# Cutting out and centralising redundent HTML code

Tags: php, html, css

i've been writing my site, however as it has evolved, i have noticed in each .html/.php file an increasing amount of repeated code such as below:

```
            <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="PUBLIC">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/NoConflict.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/uniform.agent.css" media="screen" /> 
            <style type="text/css">
            html { 
                    background: url('/resources/images/bg6.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
                    -webkit-background-size: cover;
                    -moz-background-size: cover;
                    -o-background-size: cover;
                    background-size: cover;
            }

            </style>

            <script src="/resources/jscript/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/resources/jscript/jquery.uniform.js"></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                // On load, style typical form elements
                $(function main() {
                    $("select, input, button, textarea").uniform();
                });
            </script>
            <title> Page Title </title>


            <center>
            <div class="BeautifulBox">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="SiteHome">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="ToS">ToS & Credits</a></li>
            <li><a href="resolvers">Resolvers</a></li>
            <li><a href="downloads">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="Services">Services</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <center>

            <!--This is the  logo -->
            <br/><img src="/resources/images/logo.png" width="500" height="125"></img> <br/> <br/>
            <font color=00FFFF>

            <html><style>body {color:#00FFFF;}</style>
            <div align="center" class="BeautifulBox">
            <div class="Changelist">
            <div class="Changelisttop">Title:</div>
```

And i would like to know, if there is any way i can place this into a single file, and have all the other pages link to it, whenever required (Maybe call it as a class) and so generate a LOT less clutter in each HTML/PHP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<? include 'header.php'; ?>
```

Place this in the appropriate spot in your file and it will include whatever is in `header.php`. So, if you use the exact code you provided in multiple pages, simply save that code as `header.php` and you're all set.

Comment: Or, even better, use require!

Comment: So considering not all this code is php, this would not matter, it would simply be equivalent to just pasting this code in where i have the include? And it will run the same?

Comment: @user3407675 Yes, that is correct. You can actually do something like `<?php include ("header.html"); ?>` as well. It doesn't have to be a `.php` file.

Comment: Brilliant! I just tried this and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot! It seemed so wasteful to keep copy/pasting the same code.

Comment: @user3407675 Yep, it's a great way to cut down on the clutter for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into includes.

[PHP include & require](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Edit: As a quick addition to my answer. If you find you're using the same script functions or CSS styles then it's probably better to include them in an external style sheet or script file which can be linked on each page.

Answer (score 0):

I recently noticed how often I do this, as well. One thing I sometimes do to prevent it is `include`s, like some answers say, except I have the "outside" page as one page then `include` into that page, rather than the other way around, as in the other answers. For example, instead of having file `body.php` that includes `header.php` like this:

`header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

    </head>
    <body>
```

`body.php`:

```
        <?php include("$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]" . "/header.php"); ?>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would do something like this:

`header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/body.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

`body.php`:

```
        <p>Some content</p>
```

I then have to edit my `.htaccess` so the "inside" page is the one in the URL rather than the "outside" page; you could also do this in the `Apache` (or whatever server) configuration files. I also tend to put a new `title` in the `include`d file, and then use jQuery to put it into the header. I use custom elements/attributes to do this.

You can also use `require`, instead of `include`, but this will throw an error if the file isn't found, like for example if you were a dummy & didn't include it in your website (I do this a lot). With `include`, however, you can be more flexible, perhaps having fallback pages. If you have a page you really, really need, you can `include` it, then throw a 404 error or something similar if it's not there, instead of the user seeing an ugly PHP error in the middle of the page.

Another, in my opinion better, way is to use a framework like `AngularJS`, that does all the routing for you, without PHP so you can do it all client-side (I think there's a lot of `AJAX` involved). This still often requires editing `.htaccess`.